# How Do I Control Which Programs Expand First on my Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

If I am running Google Chrome and Firefox, both with multiple windows, Chrome always expands and Firefox stacks when there's not enough space for all the windows.

Is there any way of controlling this?

(I am a web developer - that's why I have multiple browsers open).

Here's a screenshot that might help illustrate the question:

[image]

(Firefox is collapsed into a stack while Internet Explorer remains as separate buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want to acheive, but you can move around taskbar icons  in win7. did you try dragging the taskbar icons to the left or right?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to better illustrate what I mean...